# How do i run another Python file in a lower directory

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I'm creating a program that reads itself, creates itself in every lower folder currently available and then runs each of those, in turn, copying itself lower and lower until it has all available directories below it with this program in it

```
 from glob import glob
 import os
 paths = glob('*/')
 file = open("Egg.py","r")
 code = ""
 for i in file:
     code = code + i
 file.close()
 for i in paths:
     name = "Egg.py"
     name = i + name
     file = open(name,"w+")
     file.write(code)
     file.close()
     #This is where i want to execute
     # Which has the name of the file location
     # followed by Egg.py
 print("Done")
```

this is the code I have so far, the file is called 'Egg.py' and creates the same script in the folders beneath it no problem.  The issue I have is I cant then run these files as I create them to put the code in the files beneath them. Does anybody know a quick and easy way to do this? I would prefer if it was less code than more but any help at all is appreciated thanks.
for reference I have the code file next to another file like this:
Folder
Egg.py
and in the folder I have 3 other folders
FolderA
FolderB
FolderC
etc
thanks again

Comment: What are you trying to achieve in the end?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, there is no need for recursion here. You can walk down the current path using the following method:

```
import os
walk = os.walk('.')
```

Then, you iterate over this walk, copying your file in every directory:

```
# Read the contents of your current script
with open("Egg.py","r") as file:
    code = file.read()

# Explore your folders & subfolders iteratively
for root, foldernames, filenames in walk:
    with open(os.path.join(root, "Egg.py"), "w") as file:
        file.write(code)
```

Comment: That's a great help thanks a lot. I've taken this code and used it to write something else rather than itself to every file as i would have had each program execute this 'payload'  in every folder anyway but this is a much simpler and more efficient way thanks a load